# Is there any way to show actual i/o performed by a query in mysql

Tags: mysql, database, io

Is there any way to  show actual i/o performed by a query in mysql

Answer (score 1):

You can edit `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` to enable query logs by adding this to the end of this file:

```
[mysqld]
general_log=on
general_log_file=/var/log/mysql/query.log
```

Restart the mysql service and check logs by running:

`tail -f /var/log/mysql/query.log`

This answer was based [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/922521/how-to-enable-mysqls-query-log-see-all-sql-queries-as-they-come).